# Is there a way to install guest additions for Lineage OS VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I want my lineage os virtualbox be able to resize the screen and also to use my mouse where ever I want (host os or guest os) without being stucked into one so that I will be able to copy & paste and drag & drop from host to guest and vice versa.

I was able to get those functionalities on other operating systems by installing guest additions. So I wonder is there a way for android also to do the same.

It would be a great help.

Comment: I am not sure if dynamic resolution changes are supported by Android at all, as this can not happen on Android devices. Automatic capturing/releasing the mouse is AFAIR implemented by a kernel module of the virtualbox guest tools. If the used kernel supports modules you would need the mouse kernel module compiled for the used kernel (x86?). Clipboard: I think the Android clipboard works a bit different than a clipboard on Linux, so I don't think VB guest tools would work here. Same for drag & drop.